# Move System.Windows.Shapes.Shape in C#

Tags: c#, .net, move, shapes

I have `Shape` (`Path` or `Polyline`). I want to move my shape on some vector. I need to simple way in one method like this:

```
Move(shape, 0, 5);
```

How I can do this? There is there such a method in class `Shape`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [RenderTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) property with the [TranslateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform.aspx) class:

```
shape.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`TranslateTransform` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform.aspx).